# read "anonymous" json in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios

Normally I read json that is wrapped in a "data" toplevel item. But in the case below, there isn't a toplevel "data" item.

```
 [
      {
        "AreaName": null,
        "AreaId": 0,
        "DestinationName": "Alanya",
        "DestinationId": 14,
        "CountryName": "Tyrkiet",
        "CountryId": 15
      },
      {
        "AreaName": null,
        "AreaId": 0,
        "DestinationName": "Antalya",
        "DestinationId": 113,
        "CountryName": "Tyrkiet",
        "CountryId": 15
      }
 ]
```

Normally I would do something like

```
NSDictionary *temp = [[MyArray1 objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"Data"];
```

But that won't work in this case. How would I loop through the elements in the case of anonymous JSON objects like this one?

Comment: The output you show is neither a dictionary nor an array. show what `temp` prints

Comment: That listing is an array of two dictionaries.  Nothing at all complicated.

Comment: @HotLicks: I said by seeing [ and ].

Comment: I'm just going to comment that I don't really understand why this question has received so much derision or has been closed.  This is a legitimate question that has perhaps been framed badly by the OP.  It's not immediately obvious that you would use `NSMutableArray` to read anonymous JSON arrays (at least, not to us who don't work with JSON on a regular basis and are used to seeing only `NSDictionary` associated with JSON).  This question and the associated answer have been useful to me.

Answer (score 4):

1.) First create NSMutableArray with above string using

```
 jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                               options:0
                                                                 error:&error];
```

2.) Then loop for all objects in this array.

```
for(NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in jsonArray){
 NSString *name=[dictionary objectForKey:@"AreaName"];
 //and so on.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the json is not an dictionary , rather it is an Array so

```
NSMutableArray *response = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestUrlString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL] JSONValue];

for(NSDictionary *dictionary in response)
{
     NSLog(@"Data Dictionary is : %@",dictionary);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//JSON data from webservice
id json = ...
NSArray *areas = nil;
if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

   areas = json[@"Data"];

}else if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    areas = json;
}

[areas enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
     //Enumerate
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to download JSON framework from https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

And import JSON.h on top of your class. Then do the following code:

```
NSArray *arr = [responseString JSONValue];

    NSLog(@"JSOn arr count : %d",[arr count]);

    for (int i =0;i< [arr count]; i++) {

    NSDictionary *dicObj = [arr objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *strAreaName = (NSString*) [dicObj objectForKey:@"AreaName"];
    int areaID = [dicObj objectForKey:@"AreaId"];
    NSString *strDestinationName = (NSString*) [dicObj objectForKey:@"DestinationName"];
int destID = [dicObj objectForKey:@"DestinationId"];
    NSString *strCountryName = (NSString*) [dicObj objectForKey:@"CountryName"];
    int countryID = [dicObj objectForKey:@"CountryId"];

    }
```

Hope it helps.